# How to get Xpath in chrome that is same as Selenium XPath in FireFox

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, xpath, web-inspector

I have a web application which is open only in Chrome (not in Firefox and IE). I want to automate this application using Selenium, but there is no selenium recorder support for chrome.

How can I get Xpath in chrome same as Selenium XPath in FireFox

Comment: You need selenium `webDriver` not ide. `XPath` has nothing to do with this

Comment: But there is no selenium recorder support for chrome and my application is not open in firefox. How can I record actions

Comment: No way..selenium webdriver is only an option.

Comment: I am OK write tests manually but is there any way to get control properties which can help to identify control in chrome with selenium.

Comment: Yes if you use selenium webdriver then you will be able to find any element in any browser.

Comment: Yes I can find element but how do I know on which properties do I use to find element

Comment: Means? can you give me example?

Comment: using selenium web driver , you can find element by ID , class , xpath , css selector and some others..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the source. In chrome right click on the element and click inspect element it will open the source in developer console and then you can right click on the source of the element and get the xpath using copyxpath which you can use to find element. [image: Copying xpath of element Your answer]

And xpaths are same nothing to do with chrome or firefox.

Answer (score -1):

If you go by @shmaik 's answer; then you'll have to replace `"` WITH `'` in Eclipse IDE, if you are extracting xpath from google chrome.